# Staying in the USA after the expiry of my waiver

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

My waiver will expire on the 31 December 2014. Do I need a waiver all the time I am in the USA? I plan to enter the USA on the 30 December and leave on the 16 January.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're referring to your ESTA travel authorisation - if so: Direct quote from the [ESTA Q&A page](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#ata7):

> **My travel authorization is valid for travel to the United States but
>   will expire before I depart. Do I need to apply for a new one before
>   my trip?**
>
> No. ESTA travel authorization needs only to be valid upon arrival in
>   the United States.

Thus you should be fine - but do remember the immigration officers have the last say and may not necessarily like the fact you're entering the day before the ESTA expires.